# What are the ways to post a tweet to twitter with asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, twitter

i just wan to be able to post a simple "Hello World" tweet with c#...
I've tried so many things like tweetsharp, twitterizer, linq2twitter... for twitterizer i got to authenticate my apps but was unable to send the tweet most probably because it doesn't support anymore... for linq2twitter i got almost everything working but i get that "Bad Authentication Data" and I can't really find a solution... any help please? I just wan to post a simple tweet for my school project.

What are the methods/ways I can use to do it?
I'm not looking for a button to share any links or text to twitter but just sending direct messages generated by my application to twitter.. so share.this button stuff might not work for me.

Fixed: I finally got Linq2Twitter to work~!

Comment: [Simplest Method to Send Twitter Tweet and Facebook Status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474428/simplest-method-to-send-twitter-tweet-and-facebook-status)

Comment: The link provided all referred to twitterizer, as i've stated above, twitterizer does not work for me.. does it still work? it stated that it is no longer supported http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169709/twitterizer-suddenly-stopped-working